# "ValueError: Not a location id (Invalid object id)" while creating HDF5 datasets

Tags: python, numpy, object-identity

I have an numpy array(arr) of size (3997,29). I am using this array to create a dataset. This array has both integer and float variables. So dtype is reference. But when I execute it I get the below error.

> "ValueError: Not a location id (Invalid object id)"

```
with h5py.File("test1.h5", 'w') as f:
     grp = f.create_group('Nodes')

with h5py.File("test1.h5", 'r+') as f:
     grp = f.require_group('Nodes')

ref_dtype = h5py.special_dtype(ref=h5py.Reference)

arrshape = np.shape(arr)
  
dset = grp.create_dataset('Init' ,arrshape, dtype = ref_dtype , data= arr)
```

The error occurs in the last line. Below are the traceback messages

```
 dset = f.create_dataset('Init' ,arrshape, dtype = ref_dtype , data= arr)

  File "C:\Users\rupesh.n\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\group.py", line 108, in create_dataset
    dsid = dataset.make_new_dset(self, shape, dtype, data, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\rupesh.n\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\dataset.py", line 137, in make_new_dset
    dset_id = h5d.create(parent.id, None, tid, sid, dcpl=dcpl)

  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

  File "h5py\h5d.pyx", line 79, in h5py.h5d.create

ValueError: Not a location id (Invalid object id)
```

Comment: I can guess that error occurs in the last line, but usually we ask for the traceback from errors to be sure.  Another wild guess is that `f` is not open when you try to access `grp`, and that the `invalid object id` refers to `grp`.  For more than guesses we need a  [mcve].

Comment: @Vovanrock2002, Yes the error occurs in the last line. Updated traceback messages.

Comment: Issue got resolved. The file object had been closed as soon as we come out of with loop. Resolved it now.

Answer (score 20):

This error frequently occurs when someone tries to create a new dataset using a closed handle. If you are iterating make sure you are not closing the file inside of a loop. I had the same problem as OP.

Answer (score 4):

This question is a bit old, but in case anyone else ends up here with the same question I'll clear up the answer a little bit.
@WilderField is correct, but to be a little more clear.

In the last line:

`dset = grp.create_dataset('Init' ,arrshape, dtype = ref_dtype , data= arr)`

`grp` is pointing to the **Closed** `h5py.Group` that was used in:

```
with h5py.File("test1.h5", 'r+') as f:
     grp = f.require_group('Nodes')
```

Because `grp` was set to point to the group inside of the `with...` context manager `grp` is only an open group within that context manager. The HDF and all groups/datasets associated with the HDF are closed when the context manager exits. This behaviour is to prevent the HDF from being held open by lost pointers to HDF objects.

The solution is to create the `h5py.Dataset` inside of the context manager, i.e.:

```
with h5py.File("test1.h5", 'r+') as f:
     grp = f.require_group('Nodes')
     dset = grp.create_dataset('Init' ,arrshape, dtype = ref_dtype , data= arr)
```

Again, as soon as the context manager closes, `dset` will point to a **Closed** `h5py.Dataset` so unless you actually want to do something more with it, it would be sufficient to call `grp.create_dataset(...)` without assigning the return to `dset`.